# SendGrid not mailing, but not throwing any errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

This is my code:

```
userDetails = [{email:'email',id:'id'}]
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey('key');
for (const i in usersDetails) {
    const user = usersDetails[i];
    const msg = {
        from: `ZdajTo<noreply@zdajto.com>`,
        to: user.email,
        subject: `Dostepne sa nowe zadania z kategorii ${work.category}!`,
        html: `<p>Hej! Sprawdz aplikacje ZdajTo! Dostepne sa nowe zadania z kategorii ${work.category}! Aby zrezygnowac z otrzymywania emaili kliknij w <a href="https://Link/${user.id}" target="_blank">ten link</a></p>`,
    };
    calls.push(sgMail.send(msg).then(() => console.log(`Email sent to ${msg.to}`)).catch(e => console.log(e)));
}
return Promise.all(calls).then(() => console.log('Emails sent')).catch(err => console.log(8, err));
```

userDetails is an array of emails with ids.

I I used almost the same code earlier with nodemailer, and it worked well. Here's the nodemailer version:

```
for (const i in usersDetails) {
    const user = usersDetails[i];
    calls.push(mailTransport.sendMail({
        from: `ZdajTo <noreply@zdajto.com>`,
        to: user.email,
        subject: `Dostepne sa nowe zadania z kategorii ${work.category}!`,
        html: `<p>Hej! Sprawdz aplikacje ZdajTo! Dostepne sa nowe zadania z kategorii ${work.category}! Aby zrezygnowac z otrzymywania emaili kliknij w <a href="https://Link/${user.id}" target="_blank">ten link</a></p>`,
    }).catch(err => console.log(7, err, user.email)));
}
```

The weird thing is, it says `Emails sent` and `Email sent to...` every time. No error is thrown, but at the same time SendGrid says there were no requests. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is you're getting an accepted response (202) which triggers the "message sent" part. however, it doesn't guarantee that your message will be sent i just queue it to process. i would contact Sendgrid support as in this case: [Sendgrid returns 202 but doesn't send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214048/sendgrid-returns-202-but-doesnt-send-email)