# SendGrid sending not Emails using API Example in documentation

Tags: java, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using same example as given in documentation :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Email from = new Email("****@gmail.com");
    String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
    Email to = new Email("****@gmail.com");
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("API KEY");

    Request request = new Request();
    try {
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        Response response = sg.api(request);
        System.out.println("response.getStatusCode() ------------------- "+response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("response.getBody() -------- "+response.getBody());
        System.out.println("response.getHeaders() -------- "+response.getHeaders());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I can even see response code as `response.getStatusCode() ------------------- 202`

But still I dont get any emails. Any more configuration needs to be done on  `sendgrid` side which I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting mails.

The steps I followed to get the mail are as follows :

I signed up for SendGrid.

Steps :

1. Go to the Dashboard and select "Integrate using our Web API or SMTP relay"

[image]

2. Select Web API option.

[image]

3. Select your desired programming language to integrate. Here, select Java.

[image]

4. Put an API key name and click on create key to generate the random value for it.

[image]

5. Go down on the same page to generate key and click on the check box "I've integrated the above code."

Note : Implement the code given and run it. It gives no error. Then, do this :

Then, click on the button <kbd>Next:Verify Integration</kbd>.

6. It will land to the verify page.

[image]

7. Click on verify Integration button. If it gets success.

Then, it will show this :

[image]

8. Now, the code :

[image]

Output :

```
response.getStatusCode() ------------------- 202
response.getBody() -------- 
response.getHeaders() -------- {Server=nginx, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=https://sendgrid.api-docs.io, Access-Control-Allow-Methods=POST, Connection=keep-alive, X-Message-Id=ZBe5wF5WQN-TD9P4X9QEJw, X-No-CORS-Reason=https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html, Content-Length=0, Access-Control-Max-Age=600, Date=Sat, 21 Mar 2020 14:09:25 GMT, Access-Control-Allow-Headers=Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl}
```

9. Mail box : Check the Spam Folder of your mail.

[image]

Comment: I am following the same, but no email in inbox or spam, no email activity in SendGrid too.
I believe this might be the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214048/sendgrid-returns-202-but-doesnt-send-email

Comment: @NagendraSingh I have done the whole process. For me, it's working. Why is it not working for you I don't know ?

Comment: I am using Heroku and using SendGrid as addon

Comment: @NagendraSingh Can you try by enabling IMAP on the particular email address ?

Comment: @NagendraSingh It should work. Refresh mail box continously and check spam folder. SendGrid takes time to send mails what I have seen.

Comment: I reauthorized the addon and now it worked. Thanks @Anish

Comment: Done, thanks, I thought I was missing some configuration