# Getting Success when sending mail via sendgrid but not receiving the mail

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Tried using sendgrid with single sender verification to send emails with node.js, getting success in response but not receiving the mail.

In Sendgrid activity feed, status of all sent emails is stuck at processing , each one is received and processed by sendgrid but not received by gmail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sendgrid returns 202 but doesn't send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214048/sendgrid-returns-202-but-doesnt-send-email)

Comment: clarify please which endpoint you actually use with link on documentation https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference

Comment: I have used Node js

Comment: Which endpoint are you hitting? Does Marius's link above not help?

Answer (score 0):

Contacted Sendgrid support regarding the issue , the account was not activated, issue resolved